# AttributeError: 'Morsel' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python

I am trying running a cookie server using `http.cookies` module on localhost:

When I run this file using `python3` command, it raises this error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2018 15:53:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2018 15:53:45] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 303 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 48854)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 418, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 406, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "CookieServer.py", line 72, in do_GET
    message = "Hey there, " + html_escape(name)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/html/__init__.py", line 19, in escape
    s = s.replace("&", "&amp;") # Must be done first!
AttributeError: 'Morsel' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

My environment is Ubuntu 16.04, with Anaconda 3 installed.
I referred to [http.cookies documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html), but I did not figure out what `Morsel` object is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CookieServer module, you are trying to escape the value of a cookie attribute, but you are escaping a Morsel rather than the value itself.

```
>>> c = http.cookies.SimpleCookie()
>>> c['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> c['baz'] = 'quux'
>>> c
<SimpleCookie: baz='quux' foo='bar'>

# The values corresponding to cookie keys are Morsels, not strings:
>>> c['foo']
<Morsel: foo=bar>
>>> html.escape(c['foo'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/html/__init__.py", line 19, in escape
    s = s.replace("&", "&amp;") # Must be done first!
AttributeError: 'Morsel' object has no attribute 'replace'

# Use the morsel's value attribute to get the string value that you want:
>>> html.escape(c['foo'].value)
'bar'
```

So in your code, the line

`message = "Hey there, " + html_escape(name)`

should be

`message = "Hey there, " + html_escape(name.value)`